# how to test the character limit on an Input Field in playwright?

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, webautomation, playwright

I have tried the assertions they provided in Playwright docs but there is nothing regarding character length check.

Comment: Show us your DOM for the input field, and your code. Your element might have another attribute `maxlength`, asserting that the number is what you want it to be should be enough.

Comment: I haven't written any code for it as I'm confused how to check for a particular input field I saw the documentation of playwright but in that it only had assertion for length of list

Comment: Below is the code of playwright to check length of items in a list                                                                                                                                                                                             
`const length = await page.$$eval('li.selected', (items) => items.length);
expect(length === 3).toBeTruthy();`

Comment: how can i check it for character restriction on an input field

Comment: I asked you to provide your DOM and your code. You have done neither. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/tour where you can get help on how to ask better questions here.

Answer (score 2):

You could type a number of characters greater than the expected number and then check the length of the input value.
For instance, the search box in this web site has a limit of 240 characters. After typing 500 characters, if I get the input value I will get 240.

```
const { chromium } = require("playwright");

(async () => {

    const browser = await chromium.launch({ headless : false});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://stackoverflow.com/');

    await page.type('.js-search-field', Array(500).join('x'));
    console.log((await page.$eval('.js-search-field', el => el.value)).length);
    browser.close();
})();
```